# How Can I know when TScSSHShell > ScSSHShellAsyncReceive has finish recieving data from remote device?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, devart

I use the Devart SecureBridge components Pack to connect to firewall (cisco, srx...) using SSH.
I use the TScSSHShell.WriteString to execute commands and then monitor the result on the OnAsyncReceive event and I need to know **when the event has finished receiving data from the remote device?**.

Delphi 10.4.2 IDE

Comment: You can't. There is only a command return code passed back when the SSH session ends. That is why TScSSHShell.ExecuteCommand opens/closes a SSH session for each execution. You can have ExecuteCommand execute a script if you want multiple things done before returning.

Comment: I compared the returned result from ExecuteCommand and WriteString and was different, the ExecuteCommands returned a smaller number of lines for the same Command !! and because of that, I use WriteString.